# Why does the adjective “wenig” require declension in one instance, but not in another?

Tags: adjective, declension

> 1<sup>st</sup>: Das **wenige** Geld muss ausreichen.
>   2<sup>nd</sup>: Ich hab genauso **wenig** Ahnung wie du.
>   3<sup>rd</sup>: Hier haben wir **wenig** Abwechslung.

I’m not sure why in the second and third sentences, you do not need to say *wenige,* as opposed to how it works in the first sentence.

Comment: [Canoo](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Unbestimmt.html#Anchor-Unflektierte-49575) just mentions this as an exception ("uninflected in most cases in this usage") for *viel* and *wenig*, but doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is, that in (1) the noun phrase is *definite* (it contains a definite article), but in (2) and (3) the noun phrase is *indefinite* (contains an indefinite article or no article). Definiteness is one of the four grammatical properties, that influence declension of adjectives.

---

### More General:

There are four grammatical properties, that influence the declension of an adjective (when it is used attributively):

1. (grammatical) **gender**
   The gender is derived from the noun to which the attributive adjective refers:

   > - **masculine:**
   >     der Löffel – ein **kleiner** Löffel (a **small** spoon)
   > - **feminine:**
   >     die Gabel – eine **kleine** Gabel (a **small** fork)
   > - **neuter:**
   >     das Messer – ein **kleines** Messer (a **small** knife)
2. (grammatical) **case**
   The case is given by the grammatical function of the part of speech, to which the attributive adjective belongs:

   > - **nominative:**
   >     In diesem Glas ist das **frische** Wasser. (The **fresh** water is in this glas.)
   > - **genitive:**
   >     Achte auf das Glitzern des **frischen** Wassers. (Watch the sparkles of the **fresh** water.)
   > - **dative:**
   >     Ich habe dem **frischen** Wasser nichts hinzugefügt. (I added nothing to the **fresh** water.)
   > - **accusative:**
   >     Ich trinke das **frische** Wasser. (I’m drinking the **fresh** water.)
3. (grammatical) **number**
   The number of an attributive adjective matches with the number of the noun to which it refers:

   > - **singular:**
   >     ein **roter** Apfel (a **red** apple)
   > - **plural:**
   >     viele **rote** Äpfel (many **red** apples)
4. (grammatical) **definiteness**
   Only articles and attributive adjectives are influenced by definiteness, nouns are not. In a noun phrase, definiteness of article and adjective must match:

   > - **definite:**
   >     der **rote** Apfel, die **roten** Äpfel (the **red** apple, the **red** apples)
   > - **indefinite:**
   >     ein **roter** Apfel, **rote** Äpfel (a **red** apple, **red** apples)

<sub>Note 1: *Definitenes* is a relatively new concept in German grammar. The classification of German (and English) grammar is strongly influenced by the classifications for Latin language. But because Latin has no definiteness, this classification for long times was not used in German grammar. Instead you will find descriptions of *strong*, *weak* and *mixed* declension in many grammar books. But in fact *strong/weak/mixed* is based on definiteness.</sub>

<sub>Note 2: Please consult your grammar book for more details.</sub>

---

Also important:

There are three ways to use adjectives:

1. **attributvely**
   Used as an attribute of a noun.

   > Das ist ein **lustiger** Clown. (This is a **funny** clown.)
2. **predicatively**
   Used after a form of *sein* (to be), *bleiben* (to stay) and *werden* (to become). Here the  adjective is not an attribute of the clown, but via the verb *sein/bleiben/werden* still describes the noun.

   > Dieser Clown ist **lustig**. (This clown is **funny**.)
3. **adverbially**
   User after any other verb. Here the adjective no longer describes the noun. It describes the action (i.e. the verb).

   > Dieser Clown lacht **lustig**. (This clown laughs **funny**.)

This is important for declension, because only attributive adjectives will be declined. Neither predicative nor adverbial adjectives will be declined:

> - **attributive:**
>     Das ist ein **junger** Mann. Das ist eine **junge** Frau.
> - **predicative:**
>     Der Mann ist **jung**. Die Frau ist **jung**.
> - **adverbial:**
>     Der Mann sieht **jung** aus. Die Frau sieht **jung** aus.

Comment: Wenn ein »Adjektiv« adverbial verwendet wird, handelt es sich nicht mehr um das Adjektive sondern um das (oft formgleiche) Adverb. Erkennbar an der Steigerung: »Ein junger Mann – ein jüngerer Mann – der jüngste Mann«; »Der Mann ist jung – der Mann ist jünger – der Mann ist der jüngste« und »Der Mann sieht jung aus – der Mann sieht jünger aus – der Mann sieht **am jüngsten** aus«.

Comment: @Jan: Zur Frage, ob adverbiell gebraucht Adjektive Adverbien sind (nämlich modale Adverbien), findet man im Internet annähernd gleich viele Ja- wie Nein-Meinungen, und jede Seite hat gute Argumente für den eigenen Standpunkt. Letztendlich ist das, wie ich finde, ein rein akademischer Streit um des Kaisers Bart.

Comment: Doesn't explain why "wenig" and "viel" are an exception as described by [canoo](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Zahlen/Unbestimmt.html#Anchor-Unflektierte-49575) and are not inflected when used as *adjectives* (not adverbs). Also doesn't explain why the plural is inflected most of the time ("mit wenigen Ausnahmen").

Comment: @Jan: Dein Kommentar hat mir keine Ruhe gelassen. Ich glaube, du irrst dich ganz einfach. Ich habe daraus jedenfalls eine Frage gemacht: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/35454/1487