# Sind adverbielle Adjektive Adjektive oder Adverbien?

Tags: adjective, adverb, word-classes

Gestern wurde in einem [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35424/why-does-the-adjective-wenig-require-declension-in-one-instance-but-not-in-an/35426#comment87766_35426) behauptet, dass adverbielle Adjektive keine Adjektive, sondern Adverbien seien. Das würde bedeuten, dass man sie, wie auch die substantivierten Adjektive, grammatisch nicht zusammen mit anderen Adjektiven behandeln sollte, sondern eben gemeinsam mit den Adverbien. (Also vergleichbar mit den substantivierten Adjektiven, die auch nicht zu den Adjektiven, sondern zu den Substantiven gehören).

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb#Adverb_und_Adjektiv) sagt zu diesem Thema:

> a) Das *schnelle* Auto überholte.
>   b) Das Auto ist *schnell*.
>   c) Das Auto fährt *schnell*.
>
> Da immer dieselbe Wortbedeutung vorliegt, und auch sonst keine äußeren Anzeichen für einen Wortartwechsel vorliegen, kann man alle drei Vorkommen von „schnell“ unter die Wortart Adjektiv fassen, und unterscheidet dann nach der Funktion
>
> a) attributive Verwendung
>   b) prädikative Verwendung (als Teil des Prädikats *ist schnell*)
>   c) adverbielle Verwendung
>
> des Adjektivs.

Laut Wikipedia sind nur solche Wörter Adverbien, die ausschließlich in einer Funktion wie in c) verwendet werden können, nicht aber wie in a) oder b). Als Beispiel wird das Wort »*vielleicht*« genannt:

> a) <del>Der *vielleichte* Verkauf des Autos.</del>
>   b) <del>Der Verkauf ist *vielleicht*.</del>
>   c) Er verkauft *vielleicht* sein Auto.

Andere Beispiele (die nicht in Wikipedia genannt werden) dürften »*überall*«, »*gestern*« oder »*oft*« sein.

In dem eingangs verlinkten Kommentar wird aber behauptet, man könne den Unterschied zwischen einem Adjektiv und einem Adverb an der Steigerung erkennen, was mit folgendem Beispiel belegt werden soll:

> Ein junger Mann – ein jüngerer Mann – der jüngste Mann
>   Der Mann ist jung – der Mann ist jünger – der Mann ist der jüngste
>   Der Mann sieht jung aus – der Mann sieht jünger aus – der Mann sieht am jüngsten aus

Ich kann leider nicht erkenne, was mich diese Beispiele lehren sollen, und bitte daher hier um genauere Erläuterung. Insbesondere kann ich nicht erkennen, inwiefern ausgerechnet die Steigerung ein Beleg *pro* Adverb sein soll, wo doch Adverbien in der Literatur grundsätzlich als indeklinabel, also auch als nicht steigerbar, beschrieben werden. (Es gibt aber Ausnahmen: »oft - öfter - am öftesten« und »bald - eher - am ehesten«.)

Darüberhinaus bin ich nicht überzeugt davon, dass »*der Mann ist **der jüngste***« das richtige Ende der zweiten Zeile ist. Ich finde dort »*der Mann ist **am jüngsten***« passender.

In »*der Mann ist der jüngste*« würde ich »*Jüngste*« sogar groß schreiben, weil ich das für ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, also für ein Substantiv (also weder Adjektiv noch Adverb) halte. Falls ich mich in diesem Punkt irre: Wie sonst ist der Unterscheid zwischen »*Der Mann ist der jüngste.*« und »*Der Mann ist am jüngsten.*« aus grammatischer Sicht zu beschreiben? (Das ist aber nur ein Nebenthema meiner Frage.)

Meine Frage lautet:

### Sind adverbielle Adjektive Adjektive oder Adverbien?

Comment: Adverben lassen sich durchaus steigern – nicht nur in Ausnahmefällen und nicht nur im Deutschen. Im Englischen wird üblicherweise *more/most* vorangesetzt, im Französischen *plus/le plus* – wobei gerade im Französischen mit *mieux* und *pire* noch zwei deklinierte Steigerungen existieren. Allerdings ergibt bei vielen Adverben eine Steigerung semantisch keinen Sinn, weswegen sie dann auch nicht verwirklicht wird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In der bisherigen Antwort und in auch in den Kommentaren steht bereits viel Wissenswertes, aber leider eben auf viele Kommentare und eine Antwort verteilt. Zudem bin ich bei meinen Recherchen auf neue Erkenntnisse gestoßen. Daher fasse ich hier, in einer Antwort auf meine eigene Frage, die Erkenntnisse zusammen, die ich nun für richtig halte.

Vor der eigentlichen Beantwortung der Frage müssen aber zwei Sachverhalte klargestellt werden:

---

### 1. Wortarten und grammatische Funktionen sind nicht dasselbe

**Wortart**

Ein Wort gehört auch dann einer bestimmen Wortart an, wenn es außerhalb eines Satzes steht, also wenn es z.B. die Überschrift eines Wörterbucheintrags ist. Wenn ein Wort anscheinend zwei oder mehr Wortarten anzugehören scheint, dann handelt es sich in Wahrheit um mehrere Wörter, die jeweils nur einer einzelnen Wortart angehören. (Man kann bei solchen Homonymen auch anderer Ansicht sein, ich lege hier aber diesen Standpunkt zugrunde.)

Beispiel:

> Er sagt, **sein** Bruder würde bald hier **sein**.

Die beiden Instanzen von »*sein*« im obigen Satz sind zwei *verschiedene* Wörter, die unterschiedlichen Wortarten angehören (es ist nicht zweimal dasselbe Wort). Das erste »*sein*« ist ein Possessivpronomen, das zweite ist ein Vollverb. Es trifft nicht zu, dass »*sein*« zugleich ein Pronomen und ein Verb ist.

**grammatische Funktion**

Ein Wort, oder eine Gruppe von Wörtern, kann eine grammatische Funktion nur in einem Satz oder in einer satzähnlichen Wortfolge inne haben.

Dieser gegensätzliche Unterschied zwischen *intensiv* und *extensiv* allein reicht schon aus, *Wortart* und *grammatische Funktion* als voneinander verschieden zu erkennen. [Intensiv: Allein aus dem Wort selbst ableitbar. Extensiv: Durch die konkrete Einbettung in eine Umgebung (einen Satz) definiert.]

---

### 2. Adjektive und Adverbien sind nicht dasselbe

Hier wurde bereits ironisch der Vorschlag in die Diskussion eingeworfen, diese beiden Wortarten zu einer zusammenzufassen, denn dann bestünde bei der Klassifizierung Klarheit. In anderen Quellen wird dieser Ansatz sogar ernsthaft diskutiert, aber eben nur diskutiert, nicht mehr. Ich kenne keine seriöse Publikation, in der beide Wortarten tatsächlich zu einer zusammengefasst werden, und das lässt sich auch gut begründen:

- Adjektive können als Attribute von Nomen verwendet werden, Adverbien nicht.
- Adjektive werden, wenn sie attributiv verwendet werden, nach Zahl, Geschlecht, Fall und Bestimmtheit gebeugt. Adverbien werden hingegen nicht gebeugt.

Zu beiden Punkten gibt es seltene Ausnahmen:

- **attributive Adverbien**

  > Mein Freund *hier* schläft.

  Das Wort *hier* bezieht sich nicht auf die Tätigkeit, also nicht auf »schläft«, sondern auf »*mein Freund*«. Es wird hier also attributiv verwendet. Das erkennt man auch daran, dass *hier* Teil einer Nominalphrase ist (»mein Freund hier«). Attribute sind sonst meist Adjektive (wie z.B. das Wort »alt« in »mein alter Freund«).

  Dass *hier* trotz des attributiven Gebrauchs noch immer ein Adverb ist, erkennt man an zwei Dingen:

  1. Das attributive Adverb steht *hinter* dem Substantiv, das attributive Adjektiv steht *davor*.
  2. Obwohl es ein Attribut ist, wird das Adverb *nicht* gebeugt. Das Adjektiv hingegen wird bei attributiver Verwendung gebeugt.
- **Steigerung bei Adverbien**

  > Heinz kommt **oft** in die Stadt, aber Martina kommt **öfter**.

  Wie man sieht, wird das Wort »*oft*« hier gesteigert. Es wird zuerst als Positiv (»*oft*«), dann als Komparativ (»*öfter*«) verwendet. Dass »*oft*« ein Adverb ist, erkennt man daran, dass man dieses Wort nicht als Attribut vor einem Substantiv verwenden kann:

  > Falsch: Der *ofte* Heinz kommt in die Stadt.

  Es gibt nur sehr wenige Adverbien, die gesteigert werden können (*wohl, bald, gern, oft*), und es ist unter Experten ohnehin umstritten, ob Steigerungen zu den Flexionen gehören, oder ob es sich um Wortbildungen handelt.

---

Nach den einleitenden Klarstellungen folgt nun die eigentliche Antwort auf die gestellte Frage:

### adverbielle Adjektive sind keine Adverbien, sondern Adjektive

Wenn Wörter verwendet werden, um in einem Satz eine Eigenschaft eines Verbs wiederzugeben, dann werden diese Wörter *adverbiell* verwendet. Da diese Verwendung durch die Einbettung in einen Satz bestimmt ist, handelt es sich hier um eine grammatische Funktion. Diese Verwendungsart definiert also keine Wortart.

Beispiele:

> Anna fährt **schnell**.
>   Anna fährt **ausnahmsweise**.

Diese grammatische Funktion hat einen Namen. Man nennt die Wörter »*schnell*« und »*ausnahmsweise*« in den obigen Sätzen aufgrund ihrer grammatischen Funktion »**Adverbiale**«. Wichtig: *Adverbial* ist eine grammatische Funktion, vergleichbar mit *Attribut*, also ausdrücklich *keine* Wortart.

Die Wörter »*schnell*« und »*ausnahmsweise*« gehören aber verschiedenen Wortarten an. Die Bestimmung der Wortart verläuft zwar wieder über grammatische Funktionen, aber nicht über eine bestimmte Funktion, sondern darüber, in welchen Funktionen das Wort verwendet werden kann.

- **schnell**
  Dieses Wort kann als gebeugtes Attribut vor einem Substantiv innerhalb einer Nominalphrase verwendet werden:

  > ein **schneller** Läufer

  Daher ist **schnell** ein Adjektiv.
- **ausnahmsweise**
  Dieses Wort kann nicht auf diese Weise verwendet werden:

  > Falsch: <del>*ein **ausnahmsweiser** Läufer*</del>

  Daher ist »*ausnahmsweise*« kein Adjektiv, sondern etwas anderes. Da »*ausnahmsweise*«, wie oben gezeigt, zwar als Adverbial, aber eben nicht als Attribut verwendet werden kann, muss »*ausnahmsweise*« ein Adverb sein.

---

### Schlussfolgerung

Das Wort »schnell« ist in dem Satz »*Anna fährt schnell*« ein Adverbial (= grammatische Funktion), aber kein Adverb (= Wortart), sondern ein Adjektiv.

Die Argumentation für »schnell« kann auf die gleiche Weise auf alle adverbiellen Adjektive angewendet werden. Daher bleiben *alle* Adjektive auch dann weiterhin Adjektive, wenn sie Adverbiale sind. Auch dann, wenn sie aufgrund ihrer Funktion im Satz Adverbiale sind, macht das aus ihnen keine Adverbien.

Comment: Schöne Zusammenfassung. Es stellt sich mir aber dennoch die Frage, warum »sein« und »sein« unterschiedliche Wörter unterschiedlicher Wortarten sind, »schnell« und »schnell« allerdings als *ein* Wort gesehen wird.

Comment: @Jan: Du meinst vermutlich du den Imperativ singular von »schnellen« in »Mach schon! Spring! *Schnell* wie ein Blitz empor!« Ja, das ist tatsächlich ein anders Wort. Es ist ein Verb. Das Wort in »Er fährt *schnell*« ist ein Adjektiv. Die beiden Wörter bedeuten unterschiedliche Dinge und sind daher zwei verschiedene Wörter.

Comment: Hast mich gut hereingelegt ;) Nein, ich meine tatsächlich »Er läuft schnell« versus »Der schnelle Läufer«.

Comment: @Jan: Tja, das ist dasselbe Adjektiv. Einmal als Adverbial, das andere Mal als Attribut verwendet. Aber wie schon in meiner Antwort ausgeführt: *Adverbial* und *Attribut* sind Namen für grammatische Funktionen, während *Adjektiv* die Bezeichnung für eine Wortart ist.

Answer (score 3):

Anders als in vielen anderen Sprachen **bleiben** Adjektive **im Deutschen Adjektive** auch wenn sie adverbial gebraucht werden. Adverbien sind, wie im erwähnten Wikipedia-Artikel beschrieben, nur solche Wörter die ausschließlich adverbial verwendet werden können.

Das heißt die beiden Sätze:

1. Er gibt mir freundlich eine Broschüre.
2. Er gibt mir freundlicherweise eine Broschüre.

verwenden beide das Wort „freundlich“ bzw. „freundlicherweise“ als adverbiale Bestimmung der Art und Weise.

Allerdings handelt es sich bei „freundlich“ um ein Adjektiv, da es auch als Attribut bebraucht werden, z.B. in „der freundliche Handelsvertreter“.

Dagegen ist eine attributive Verwendung bei „freundlicherweise“ nicht möglich (<del>„der freundlicherweise Handelsvertreter“</del>). Somit ist dieses Wort ein Adverb.

#### Nachtrag:

Anders als oben angegeben, können Adverbien auch in anderen Zusammenhängen verwendet werden. Das „ausschließlich“ ist dahingehend zu spezifizieren, dass sie nicht attributiv gebraucht werden können. Allerdings gibt es durchaus andere Verwendungsmöglickeiten von Adverbien. So können diese beispielsweise auch dazu verwendet werden, Adjektive abzuschwächen oder zu verstärken.
Zum Beispiel:

1. Ich fürchte mich sehr.
2. Ich bin ein sehr ängstlicher Mensch.
3. Das Auto fährt sehr schnell.

Im ersten Satz wird „sehr“ im oben genannten Sinne als adverbiale Bestimmung verwendet. Im zweiten und dritten Satz intensiviert es ein Adjektiv, welches im zweiten Satz attributiv und im dritten Satz adverbial verwendet wird.

Comment: Also, wenn ein Adjektiv adverbial gebraucht wird, ist es wohl ein Adverb. Sonst kann man es adverbial nicht verwenden. In deinem Beispielsatz ist "freundlich" also ein Adverb, auch wenn das Wort ansich grundsätzlich auch ein Adjektiv ist. Und die beiden Sätze haben eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung. "freundlich" != "freundlicherweise"

Comment: Nach mehrheitlicher Meinung bleibt es ein Adjektiv. Vergleiche dazu auch [mit dem Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb#Adverb_und_Adjektiv) und den dort angegebenen Referenzen. Aus diesem Grund ist es auch nicht möglich (zumindest ist mir kein Beispiel eingefallen) ein Adjektiv und ein Adverb mit gleicher Bedeutung zu finden.

Comment: @Em1: Aus deiner Behauptung »wenn ein Adjektiv *adverbial* gebraucht wird, ist es wohl ein *Adverb*« könnte man im Analogieschluss ableiten: *wenn ein Adjektiv *attributiv/prädikativ* gebraucht wird, ist es wohl ein *Attribut/Prädikat*« Nur gib es die Wortarten »Attribut« und »Prädikat« gar nicht. Das sind grammatische Funktionen, aber keine Wortarten. Die Wortart ist, wie ich glaube, in allen Fällen dieselbe. Es handelt sich in allen Fällen um *Adjektive*, die nur in drei verschiedenen grammatischen Funktionen verwendet werden.

Comment: @Em1 Durch bloßen Gebrauch ändert sich die Wortart nicht - Wenn ich mit der Beißzange Nägel in die Wand haue, wird sie dadurch kein Hammer.

Comment: <ironie>Ok, dann ist ab heute ein Adjektiv eine Wortart, die Verben, Adjektive und andere Adverbien modifiziert. Eigentlich das, was dem Adverb zugeschrieben ist, womit aber diese Wortart nun überflüssig ist. Dann können wir jetzt die verbliebenen Adverbien (zu denen es kein Adjektiv gibt), auch noch zu Adjektive umbenennen und haben somit die Grammatik vereinfacht. Wir müssen uns jetzt nicht mehr um Adverbien scheren. Super Sache.</ironie>

Comment: @Em1: Dieser Ansatz wurde durchaus schon ernsthaft diskutiert, vor allem deswegen, weil Adverbien hauptsächlich durch das Fehlen von Eigenschaften definiert sind (sie sind nicht flektierbar, sie können nicht attributiv verwendet werden). Eigenschaften, die Adverbien haben (z.B. können sie ganz allein die Position 1 eines Aussagesatzes besetzen: »*Hier* kommt Kurt.«), lassen sich immer in anderen Wortarten auch finden (»*Lustig* lachte der Clown.«)

Comment: @sannaj: Vielleicht solltest du ergänzen, dass es auch Adverbien gibt, die prädikativ (und in seltenen Fällen sogar attributiv) verwendet werden können: Also nicht nur: »Mein Freund schläft *hier*« sondern auch »Mein Freund ist *hier*«. (Aber nicht: »Der *hiere* Freund schläft«). Im Fall von »*hier*« ist sogar ein attributiver Gebrauch möglich: »Mein Freund *hier* schläft.« In diesem Satz bezieht sich *hier* nicht auf das Verb *schläft*, sondern auf das Substantiv *Freund*, und ist mit diesem Substantiv direkt verbunden (also nicht vermittels eines Verbes).

Comment: (Fortsetzung):  Der Unterschied zu einem Adjektiv (wie z.B. »alt«) ist aber: Das attributive Adverb steht *hinter* den Substantiv und wird *nicht gebeugt* (»*mein Freund hier*«). Das attributive Adjektiv steht *vor* dem Substantiv und wird *sehr wohl gebeugt* (»*mein alter Freund*«). Dass es sich in beiden Fällen um Attribute handelt, erkennt man auch daran, dass die Bestandteile einer Nominalphrase sind.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Schreib doch eine Antwort, würde dir gern +1 für die Details geben.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ich habe zwar die Frage gestellt, aber ich überlege tatsächlich, alle Argumente selbst in einer Antwort zusammenzuschreiben. Ich warte aber noch ein wenig ab, vielleicht schreibt ja noch jemand eine zufriedenstellende Antwort.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Es ist ja auf SE generell erwünscht, auch die eigenen Fragen zu beantworten.