# Wird das Wort »angestrengt« in »angestrengt nachdenkend« als Adverb benutzt?

Tags: adverb

Ich studiere Thomas Manns Roman *Boddenbrooks* im Original. Darin findet sich:

> angestrengt nachdenkend

Ist das Wort *angestrengt* hier ein Adverb? Und wie könnte man diese zwei Wörter übersetzen? Passt Folgendes?

> intensely pondering

Comment: Kurze Antwort: Ja.

Comment: Kurze Antwort: Nein. Die Formulierung »als Adverb benutzt« ist unsinnig, weil »Adverb« keine grammatische Funktion, sondern eine Wortart ist. Richtig wäre: »als Adverbial benutzt« (was mit »ja« zu beantworten wäre, aber nicht gefragt wurde). Die Frage »Ist das Wort *angestrengt* hier ein Adverb?« hingegen ist eindeutig, und die Antwort darauf lautet ganz klar: Nein. Die Übersetzung in eine andere Sprache als Deutsch ist hier off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Nein.

*angestrengt* ist das Partizip von *anstrengen*, dass hier in *adverbialer Verwendung* eingesetzt wird.

Dadurch, dass  ein Wort für einen bestimmten Zweck eingesetzt wird, ändert sich seine Wortart nicht - Wenn man mit einer Zange einen Nagel on die Wand klopft, wird sie deswegen kein Hammer.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist der Zusatz zum Adjektiv nachdenkend und somit ein Adverb, ja ;)

Comment: Ja, ich wollte nur vergewissern mich darüber, dass ich Recht hatte. Danke.

Comment: *Es ist der Zusatz zum Adjektiv nachdenkend und somit ein **Adverbial***, aber Adverbiale sind etwas anderes als Adverbien. Das eine (Adverbial) ist eine grammatische Funktion, das andere (Adjektiv) ist eine Wortart.

Comment: Danke für deinen Einwurf, wieder etwas gelernt.

Comment: Wenn ich eine Geige als Fliegenklatsche benutze, wird sie dadurch nicht zur Fliegenklatsche, sondern bleibt Geige. Trotzdem sagt man, dass sie in diesem Fall "als Fliegenklatsche" benutzt wird. Warum sollte es falsch sein zu sagen, dass das Partizip hier "als Adverb" benutzt wird?

Comment: @KilianFoth: Weil in der Grammatik ein eigener Begriff für »Verwendung als Fliegenklatsche« existiert. Die Geige heißt »Adjektiv«, die Fliegenklatsche heißt »Adverb«, und etwas das man als Fliegenklatsche verwendet, heißt »Adverbial«. Dieses Adverbial kann sowohl eine Geige (Adjektiv) sein, als auch eine Fliegenklatsche (Adverb), oder sogar eine Ansammlung mehrerer Gegenstände (eine Gruppe von mehreren Wörtern, die ganz verschiedenen Wortarten angehören, z.B. »nach Baden bei Wien«)

Answer (score 0):

### Nein

»Angestrengt« ist ein Adjektiv, das hier als Adverbial verwendet wird, aber das macht daraus noch lange kein Adverb.

Kurz das Wichtigste:

- **Adjektiv**
  Das ist eine Wortart, so wie auch *Adverb* eine (andere) Wortart ist. Ein Wort gehört auch ohne grammatischen Kontext einer ganz bestimmten Wortart an (z.B. wenn es nur die Überschrift eines Wörterbucheintrages ist). Die konkrete grammatische Funktion innerhalb eines Satzes ändert nichts an der Wortart, zu der ein Wort gehört.
- **Adverbial; adverbielle Verwendung**
  Das ist eine grammatische Funktion innerhalb eines Satzes. Innerhalb des Satzes »Angestrengt nachdenkend runzelte Ilse ihre Stirn« wird das Adjektiv (Wortart) »angestrengt« als Adverbial (grammatische Funktion) verwendet, aber es ist trotzdem kein Adverb (Wortart).

Detailierter wird das in dieser Frage behandelt: [Sind adverbielle Adjektive Adjektive oder Adverbien?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35454/1487)

Comment: *angestrengt* ist, genaugenommen, kein Adjektiv.

Comment: @tofro: Da musst du dich mit der Duden-Redaktion streiten, nicht mit mir: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/angestrengt Ich war mir auch unsicher, und habe daher das Wort nachgeschlagen. Aber, wie ich gerade bemerkt haben, gibt dir Wikitionary recht: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/angestrengt Das Problem mit Partizipien scheint generell zu sein, dass sie eine Zwitterstellung einnehmen.

Comment: Das ist sehr klar. Danke.