# Was modifiziert "tief" in diesem verwirrenden Satz «Leben und Bewußtsein tief zerklüftenden Wende und Grenze spielt»?

Tags: sentence-structure

Warum ist tief nicht tiefe?

> Um aber einen klaren Sachverhalt nicht künstlich zu verdunkeln: die
>   hochgradige Verflossenheit unserer Geschichte rührt daher, daß sie vor
>   einer gewissen, **Leben und Bewußtsein tief zerklüftenden Wende und
>   Grenze spielt**. . . Sie spielt, oder, um jedes Präsens geflissentlich
>   zu vermeiden, sie spielte und hat gespielt vormals, ehedem, in den
>   alten Tagen, der Welt vor dem großen Kriege, mit dessen Beginn so
>   vieles begann, was zu beginnen wohl kaum schon aufgehört hat.

Das kommt aus dem Vorsatz von "Der Zauberberg" von Thomas Mann

---

Es scheint, T. Mann verwendet undekliniert wörter mit ähnlichen Platzierung oft:

A:

> er saß bei niedergelassenem Fenster, und da der Nachmittag sich mehr
>   und mehr verkühlte, so hatte er, Familiensöhnchen und Zärtling, den
>   Kragen seines **modisch** weiten, auf Seide gearbeiteten
>   Sommerüberziehers aufgeschlagen.

Und:

B:

> Es ist eine Schmalspurbahn,
>   die man nach längerem Herumstehen in windiger und **wenig**
>   reizvoller Gegend besteigt, und in dem Augenblick, wo die kleine,
>   aber offenbar ungewöhnlich zugkräftige Maschine sich in Bewegung
>   setzt, beginnt der eigentlich abenteuerliche Teil der Fahrt,
>   ein jäher und zäher Aufstieg, der nicht enden zu wollen scheint.

B könnte ein adverb sein aber für A ich bin nicht sicher...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Satz ist schon ziemlich tricky...

*tief* beschreibt *zerklüftende* näher (das Partizip I von "zerklüften"), das seinerseits ein Attribut von "Wende und Grenze" ist.

Im Englischen würde das etwa so etwas wie

> deeply life and conciousness-indenting turn and boundary

heissen.

*tief* hat in diesem Satz keine Verbindung zu irgendeinem Substantiv, kann also nicht zusammen mit einem gebeugt werden.

Comment: Es ist verwirrend, nein? Ich denke, «zerklüftenden» sollte «zerklüftende» sein

Comment: Nein. "...sie vor einer **Wende** und **Grenze** spielt" ist Dativ, "zerklüftende", dass  ein Attribut davon ist, muss dem folgen, und wird zu *zerklüftende**n*** flektiert.

Comment: .. Und zwar weil es hier schwach gebeugt ist, weil es _einer_ folgt. Wenn es stark gebeugt wäre (also _der_ folgen würde) hieße es ebenfalls _zerklüftenden_, aber wenn es gemischt gebeugt wäre, davor also kein Artikel o.ä. stünde, müsste es _zerklüftende**r**_ heißen.

Comment: @user135711, aus dem gleichen Grunde ist „tiefe“ keine Option, bestenfalls „tiefen“. Und dafür müsste es vor „Lebem“ stehen. Und natürlich wäre die Bedeutung eine andere.

Comment: @sgf Danke, ich verstehe jetzt. Kleine Korrektur: swache=der
stark=kein artikel
gemischt=ein

Comment: @user135711 Danke! Ich war mir bei der Terminologie so sicher, dass ich mir nicht mal die Mühe gemacht habe, sie zu überprüfen...

Answer (score 2):

Tofro hat in seiner Antwort schon erklärt, dass *»tief«* keine Eigenschaft eines Substantiv angibt, sondern eine Eigenschaft eines Adjektivs:

> Frage: Wie (auf welche Weise) sind Wende und Grenze zerklüftet?
>   Antwort: Sie sind *tief* zerklüftet.

Ein Wort, dass die grammatische Funktion erfüllt, bei welche die Eigenschaften von Adjektiven oder Verben angeben wird, heißt »Adverbial«.

Von dieser grammatische Funktion ist die Wortart »Adverb« zu unterscheiden. (Wörter wie »vielleicht« oder »heute« sind Adverbien. Aber »tief« ist ein Adjektiv, das, wie fast alle Adjektive, auch die grammatische Funktion eines Adverbials haben kann.)

Eine ausführliche Diskussion der Begriffe *Adjektiv*, *Adverb* und *Adverbial* findet man in der Frage »[Sind adverbielle Adjektive Adjektive oder Adverbien?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35454/1487)«

Answer (score 2):

Ich drücke den Satz etwas anders aus; das sollte es klarer machen:

Die Geschichte spielt vor einer gewissen Wende und Grenze, die das Leben und Bewußtsein tief zerklüftet.