# Das Suffix "-übergreifend"

Tags: meaning

Zum Beispiel:

> Generationsübergreifend benutzen wir das Internet.
>
> Fachübergreifendes Wissen

Welche Bedeutung hat dieses Suffix und lässt es sich beliebigen Adjektiven anhängen oder nur bestimmten?

Comment: "Generationsübergreifend" means, more or less, "spanning (several) generations". "Fachübergreifend" means "interdisciplinary" or "multi-disciplinary", etc. I guess you get the idea: it literally means "reaching over the boundaries" of a certain subject, like a generation, a discipline, a time period, an ethnicity, a city, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> und lässt es sich beliebigen **Adjektiven** anhängen

Nicht **Adjektiven**, sondern **Substantiven**

> Welche Bedeutung hat dieses Suffix

Das aus Substantiv und "-übergreifend" gebildete Adjektiv besagt, dass irgendetwas zu mehreren oder allen "Dingen" gehört, die das Substantiv beschreibt und nicht nur zu einem einzigen.

Beispiel: "***Fach***übergreifendes Wissen"

=> Dieses Wissen gehört nicht zu einem bestimmten Fach, sondern zu verschiedenen Fächern.

Als Adverb bedeutet es, dass sich der Satz nicht nur auf ein bestimmtes "Ding" bezieht, sondern auf mehrere "Dinge" die das Substantiv beschreibt.

Beispiel: "***Generations***übergreifend"

Nicht nur eine bestimmte Generation von Personen tut etwas bestimmtes, sondern mehrere oder (in diesem Fall) alle.

> oder nur bestimmten?

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es sich theoretisch an alle Substantive anhängen lässt, in vielen Fällen die Bedeutung des entstandenen Wortes aber unsinnig wäre.

Comment: Faustregel: Ein Adverb kann niemals Attribut eines Substantivs sein, und wird niemals gebeugt. Ein Adjektiv kann sehr wohl ein Attribut eines Substantivs sein, und wird in diesem Fall auch gebeugt. In »fachübergreifend**es** Wissen« ist *fachübergreifend* ein Attribut von »Wissen« und wird gebeugt (von dieser Beugung kommt die Endung *»es«*). Daher sind »fachübergreifend«, generationsübergreifend« uns ähnliche Wörter keine Adverbien, sondern Adjektive.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Mit dem Wort "Ding" war jeweils das Substantiv gemeint, aus dem das Adjektiv oder Adverb gebildet wird; also das Substantiv "Generation" beim Adverb "generationsübergreifend".

Comment: Mir ging es ja auch nicht um das Wort »Ding«, sondern um das Wort »**Adverb**« ziemlich in der Mitte deiner Antwort. »Fachübergreifend, generationsübergreifend« und ähnliche Wörter keine Adverbien, sondern Adjektive.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Prinzipiell kann im Deutschen jedes Adjektiv als Adverb benutzt werden und umgekehrt. Beispiel: "Das Auto ist schnell" (schnell = Adjektiv) vs. "das Auto fährt schnell" (schnell = Adverb). Im Beispielsatz des Fragestellers war "generationsübergreifend" eindeutig ein Adverb.

Comment: Nö. Adjektive bleiben auch dann Adjektive, wenn man sie als Adverbiale verwendet. https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35454/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe mir gerade den Artikel "Adverb" in Wikipedia durchgelesen. Laut Abschnitt 1.2 scheint zwar die Mehrheit der Sprachwissenschaftler genau dieser Meinung zu sein, ein kleinerer Teil jedoch scheint von "Adjektivadverbien" zu sprechen und diese als Adverbien zu klassifizieren. Eine offizielle Regelung, welche von beiden Meinungen korrekt ist, scheint nicht zu existieren.